# What's the best .Rnw editor?

Tags: r, sweave, knitr

I'm trying to find out what people use for editing `.Rnw` files.

Desirable features are:

- Auto `R` code completion
- Auto `LaTeX` code completion
- Cross platform
- Automatic display of `R` function documentation
- Spell check
- Simple `R` console access
- Syntax highlighting for both `R` code and `LaTeX` code
- Document structure
- Function extraction tool for `R` code. With this, the user highlights a chunk of code that produces a value and the tool converts this into a function with the appropriate inputs and value.

Comment: Suggested desirable features would also be helpful for the question.

Comment: Since I don't use that kind of file I'm not sure but maybe Geany could work.

Comment: Maybe someone could comment on texnicle: http://www.bobsoft-mac.de/texnicle/texnicle.html. Unfortunately is for MAC only.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like emacs+ess+auctex. I think it hits all your points, but unfortunately it has an epic learning curve.

Comment: It would be fantastic if someone put together a setup guide for this (including all the bells and whistles stuff) - I know all the pieces exist in various places but it's a nightmare to put it all together.

Answer (score 1):

I use TexStudio (sometimes RStudio - see my other answer).

- Auto R code completion (No)
- Auto LaTeX code completion (Yes)
- Cross platform (Yes)
- Automatic display of R function documentation (No)
- Spell check (Yes, and some grammar check)
- Simple R console access (No)
- Syntax highlighting for both R code and LaTeX code (No)
- Document structure (Yes)
- Function extraction tool (No)

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes use RStudio (usually TexStudio - see my other answer).

- Auto R code completion (Yes)
- Auto LaTeX code completion (No)
- Cross platform (Yes)
- Automatic display of R function documentation (Yes)
- Spell check ([Yes](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551916-Spelling-Dictionaries))
- Simple R console access (Yes)
- Syntax highlighting for R code (Yes)
- Syntax highlighting for LaTeX code (No)
- Document structure (No)
- Function extraction tool (Yes)

Comment: Rstudio has spell check https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200551916-Spelling-Dictionaries